# jquery for loop is not working in dialog div button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is jQuery code while button click the for loop is not working in dialog div submit date button please some one help me friends. . .

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit Date": function () {
            for (var j = 1; j <= MGDval; j++) {
                alert($('S' + j).val());
            }
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

Comment: where is you MGDval is defined?

Comment: that is global variable value is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert($('S'+j).val());
```

change to :

```
alert($('#S'+j).val()); // => for ID

alert($('.S'+j).val()); // => for Class
```

if selector element "S" : "#S" or ".S"

Answer (score 0):

```
s does nor refer to any thing chnage to .s for class or #s for Id

alert($('#S'+j).val());

alert($('.S'+j).val());
```